# Grails 2.5.0 - Fast lookup of items in collection over a domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following code for sending internal messages over the web app:

Domain:

```
class Mail {
    ...
    User from
    static hasMany = [to: User]
    ...
}
```

What I want to do is enable a User who logs in and is addressed in the "to" field to view all the Mails addressed to them. It's easy to do this with the "from" field using:

```
def totalMails = Mail.countByFrom(user)
...
def mails = Mail.findAllByFrom(user, [max: rows, offset: offset])
```

Doing this with the "to" field is more difficult, and I'm not sure how to do it and make the lookups fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use criteria, where, or HQL queries. The HQL query will give you an idea of how the criteria and where queries work at the database level.

## Criteria

```
def totalMails = Mail.createCriteria().get {
    to {
        eq('id', user.id)
    }

    projections {
        count('id')
    }
}

def mails = Mail.createCriteria().list(max: rows, offset: offset) {
    to {
        eq('id', user.id)
    }
}
```

## Where

```
def totalMails = Mail.where {
    to.id == user.id
}.count()

def mails = Mail.where {
    to.id == user.id
}.list(max: rows, offset: offset)
```

## HQL

```
def totalMails = Mail.executeQuery 'select count(m) from Mail as m inner join m.to as t where t.id = :id', [id: user.id]

def mails = Mail.executeQuery 'select m from Mail as m inner join m.to as t where t.id = :id', [id: user.id], [max: rows, offset: offset]
```

Comment: Would the Criteria and HQL be faster than the Where? The Where version looks like it returns all the Mails and then does the operation. I'd ideally like this to be able to quickly get a set of 20 Mails out of 20k from a person with millions of records.

Comment: No. `Mail.where(Closure)` creates an instance of DetachedCriteria. The `DetachedCriteria.count()` method adds a count projection (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/CountProjection.html), runs the query, and returns a single result. It does the same thing as the criteria and HQL.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/8b0672e3e5047593037e556da111294acbcaf8af/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/grails/gorm/DetachedCriteria.groovy